# Adjective that means ‘having agency’

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I’m looking for an adjective that means the person described has the power to choose their own actions, rather than being someone else’s puppet.  *Potent* is the closest I’ve come but it’s not right.

The context is a reaction I’m writing to the conquistador [Bernal Díaz del Castillo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernal_D%C3%ADaz_del_Castillo)’s account of the [*Historia verdadera de la conquista de la Nueva España*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historia_verdadera_de_la_conquista_de_la_Nueva_Espa%C3%B1a) (meaning the “True History of the Conquest of New Spain”), in which he describes certain actions on the part of [La Malinche, a Nahua woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Malinche) who served [Hernán Cortés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hern%C3%A1n_Cort%C3%A9s) as interpreter and concubine, and was a Christian convert. The discussion is about how realistic Díaz’s portrayal is, specifically regarding a passage where Cortés’s party visits the town where Malinche had been given by her family to human traffickers years earlier, and Díaz, retelling the events 50 years later, says Malinche forgave them, gave them unreasonably fine gifts, and sets for them a Christian example of devotion to her new Spanish husband (not Cortés, someone else), no doubt with proselytizing intent.

What I’d like to say with a single adjective is something that conveys autonomy on her part, independence, initiative, freedom from the influence of the soldiers she came with. Is there a word related to “possessing agency” which fills in this blank?

> I’m not generally a cynical person but regarding the Conquistadors
> and the Church, you don’t even have to be cynical to recognize that
> they embellished their writing, and Christianizing an Indian woman and
> making her out to be more pure, forgiving, and _______________ than
> realistic makes the Spaniards look good.

Words which don’t fit because they either don’t capture the whole connotation or are too tortured to sound reasonable include: *autonomous, potent, vital, independent, self-actualized, agency-having*, and so on.

Comment: How about *empowered*?

Comment: You've already written *something that conveys autonomy on her part*. I can't see any reason why you don't want to use *autonomous*. All the other characteristics you mention *(independence, initiative, freedom from the influence of the soldiers)* are implicit in *autonomous*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sure, it wouldn't be exactly wrong but it wouldn't emphasize what I want to emphasize or feel/sound the way I want to write, those are the reasons.

Comment: Americans say empowerment and empowered. I think your blank would be a simple: powerful.

Comment: What is wrong with "autonomous" or "independent"?

Comment: "independent" is the answer; "autonomous" is generally not used for individual humans, but for sociopolitical groups, or machines. *"empowered"* is some late 20th-C US buzzword that has become devalued to meaninglessness by psychobabble, management-speak and a thousand Dilberts.

Comment: @smci Not entirely true. My daughter's second-grade class had a speaker brought in to empower them, and the effects were clear. My daughter got the power to stop time. Her best friend can fly now.

Comment: @smci Surely “having agency” has also “become devalued to meaninglessness by psychobabble, management-speak and a thousand Dilberts”, no? [She was one of twenty enslaved women given to the conquistadors to use as servants and sexual objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Malinche#The_Conquest_of_Mexico). Cortés seems to have eventually freed her, replacing her with a new slave. That she may have been allowed to make certain decisions on her own does not mean that as a once-enslaved native woman she ever enjoyed the freedoms of a white man then and there in that awful medieval world.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One word for this is **autonomous**, defined by Merriam-Webster as:

> existing or capable of existing independently

Collins defines it as

> An autonomous person makes their own decisions rather than being influenced by someone else.
>
> *Autonomous individuals are those who follow their own courses of action relatively unimpeded by others*

Another that’s less formal and more common is **independent**, but the connotations feel slightly different to me.  Being capable of existing independently is a closer match for “having agency” than being independent.

Comment: Both good words. The OP dismisses them for reasons I fail to understand.

Comment: @StuartF it’s true that they do mention them. If they mean something slightly different, it’s going to be hard to express that when even a longer explanation doesn’t get the meaning across.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, though I actually went with "empowered" but Jim put his answer in a comment.

Comment: @Beanluc Thanks. [Empowered is a great one, too.](https://www.theonion.com/women-now-empowered-by-everything-a-woman-does-1819566746)

Answer (score 6):

Surely 'cynical', 'Conquistadors', 'embellished' and 'Christianizing' demonstrate a high register, with which 'autonomous' fits well? (I'd also add an 'is' before 'realistic' here.)

**Self-determining** is another possibility:

> *self-determining* [adjective]
>
> ...
>
> (of a person) having the power or freedom to control their own life.
>
> - "the individual feels competent and self-determining"

[[Oxford Languages, via Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=self-determining&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=YAY_Y4qQDcGS8gK18ZLIAQ&ved=0ahUKEwiKwKb4hsz6AhVBiVwKHbW4BBkQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=self-determining&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwgAEIAEEAoyBwgAEIAEEAoyBwgAEIAEEAoyBwgAEIAEEAoyBwgAEIAEEAoyBwgAEIAEEAoyBwgAEIAEEAoyBwgAEIAEEAoyBwgAEIAEEAoyBwgAEIAEEApKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFgAYPwDaABwAXgAgAFRiAFRkgEBMZgBAKABAqABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz)]

Comment: in the same vein of "self-determining": "self-directed" is another possibility

Answer (score 6):

Could you rephrase slightly?:

> I'm not generally a cynical person but regarding the Conquistadors and the Church, you don't even have to be cynical to recognize that they embellished their writing, and Christianizing an Indian woman and making her out to be more pure, forgiving and possessing more agency than realistic makes the Spaniards look good.

Alternatively, if you want to maintain the parallel structure:

> Christianizing an Indian woman and making her out to be purer, more forgiving and higher-agency than realistic makes the Spaniards look good.

Moving "more pure" to "purer" and folding "more" into "more forgiving" instead of the start of the list means you remove the awkwardness of "more high agency" in the original phrasing.

Comment: These are good suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

The standard adjective seems to fit:

OED

> **agential**, adj.
>
> **Of, belonging, or relating to an agent or agency (in various senses of the nouns); that is or acts as an agent.**
>
> 1843   J. O. Dakeyne Baptismal Regeneration 57   *I was not
> aware..that her [sc. the Church's] part in the matter of administering the hallowing the rite [of Baptism] was anything more than agential.*
>
> 1872   F. Hall Rec. Exempl. False Philol. 60   *To obtain an agential substantive complementing the verb photograph.*
>
> 2003   L. K. Graham in J. N. Poling & C. C. Neuger Men's Work in
> Preventing Violence against Women v. xxi. 368   *Until she sought
> help..Anna was a rather helpless receptor..of her husband's agential
> power used violently to subordinate and control her.*

Comment: Thanks, I like this because it is standard and is derivative of precisely the word I want to use. It doesn't seem like it applies to a person indicating possession of the trait, though. Anna's husband's power is agential, but I don't think we'd say the man is. Same with the administress of the baptism - her part was agential, I don't think we'd say she was. The third example (second in your order) isn't even talking about a person, and describes function, not attribution. I'll consider whether "agentious" is likely to be understood by my audience and not sound too made-up.

Comment: You can be agential in doing something. The adjective is not merely attributive, it can be predicative.

Comment: Honestly. I'm not sure I'd want to use this. I've never heard it in my life, so probably most readers haven't, either, and on first seeing it I read it as a-genital meaning without genitals. Not the impression you want to give to your readers :D

Comment: It's in the OED and Merriam-Webster but not Macmillan or Cambridge; it seems to be used in psychology and philosophy of mind but not outside academia. I'd be sceptical about using such a rare word in a non-social-science text unless you are certain its meaning can be inferred from context and morphology.

Comment: Agentic. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agentic#:~:text=agentic%20(comparative%20more%20agentic%2C%20superlative,(introduced%20in%20Milgram's%20theory).

Comment: [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+agency%2Chave+agency%2Chaving+agency%2Cagentic%2Cagential&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20agency%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20agency%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chaving%20agency%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cagentic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cagential%3B%2Cc0) is interesting, suggesting this and other "agency"-based words and phrases are new and may not have settled down yet.

Answer (score 2):

Just making @Jim's comment under the question an answer:

[**Empowered**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empowered) was the first word that came to my mind as well. The Merriam-Webster entry defines it as

> having the knowledge, confidence, means, or ability to do things or make decisions for oneself.

This describes exactly what you want to express about La Malinche.

Answer (score 1):

***Spirited*** fits the context well, and implies lively and courageous behaviour - very much related to independence and initiative.

> The abrupt departure of Miss Butterworth left Mr. Belcher piqued and
> surprised. Although he regarded himself as still " master of the
> situation " to use his own pet phrase, - - the visit of that
> ***spirited*** woman had in various ways humiliated him. To sit in his own library, with an intruding woman who not only was not afraid of
> him but despised him, to sit before her patiently and be called " Bob
> Belcher, " and a brute, and not to have the privilege of kicking her
> out of doors, was the severest possible trial of his equanimity. She
> left him so suddenly that he had not had the opportunity to insult
> her, for he had fully intended to do this before she retired. (Sevenoaks; Holland, J. G.)
>
> He was high on our list of special victims to be paid off for atrocities in Missouri. But his wife saved him by rolling him up inside a rug, dragging him out into the backyard and piling furniture on top of him, while we set fire to their house and stood around waiting for him to emerge. Another ***spirited*** woman, like Mrs. Lane, whom I have to admire. It's a wonder to me how those miserable Jayhawking bastards could have won the devotion of such fine brave women. (Confessions of Johnny Ringo; Geoff Aggeler)

Comment: Also, while it might not fit well in this context, the more informal *spunky*.

Answer (score 0):

The Christian lingo is "conviction".

Most Christian clergy 100 years ago would express antisemitism such as this

- I feel the conviction of the holy spirit to convert Jews and make them realise their rebellion for rejecting the lord Jesus Chris.

Such antisemitism is still widespread, though.

conviction (kənˈvɪkʃən)
n

1. the state or appearance of being convinced
2. a fixed or firmly held belief, opinion, etc
3. the act of convincing
4. (Law) the act or an instance of convicting or the state of being convicted
5. carry conviction to be convincing
   conˈvictional adj

Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014 © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2014

Answer (score 0):

"self-reliant" might fit your context well.

Answer (score 0):

You could write *possessed of agency*, or *agency-possessing*. *Possessing agency* would also work, though I'm not certain it's MLA-standard grammar.

> making her out to be more pure, forgiving and *possessed of agency*
> than realistic

> making her out to be more pure, forgiving and *agency-possessing* than
> realistic

> making her out to be more pure, forgiving and *possessing agency* than realistic

The last version could be reworded:

> making her out to be more pure and forgiving, and *possessing more
> agency*, than realistic

While *agential* appears to be a word, it's not very common (my browser says it's not a real word), and I'm not sure a reader would know what it meant. The sentences above are less likely to cause confusion.

Also, I'm not sure it's accurate in this context. Merriam-Webster [defines it as](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agential) "related to, or expressive of, an agent or agency", where "agency" refers to a group of people, not the concept of free-will. The Free Dictionary [defines it as](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/agential) "Used to describe a case of nouns that identify the person performing the action of a verb, for example, 'singer'." (Though it also misspelled "performing", so I'm not sure how reliable it is.) On the other hand, Wikipedia has an article on [agential realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agential_realism) that uses the term more like you are intending, so it could be fine.

As for word choice, I'm not sure whether agency or autonomy is more accurate to what you're describing here. In general, agency is the ability to affect the world around you, while autonomy is acting without people guiding your every step.

In your example, we might talk about her agency being limited, in that she's not allowed to behave in a manner perceived as non-Christian. Or we might talk about her autonomy being limited, in that she's not allowed to interact with the village locals without constant supervision.

(After writing this, I noticed your comment that *agency-having* wasn't a good fit. I think *agency-possessing* is better, but *having agency* sounds like it would work in your example too.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for *uncoerced* or *acting on her own volition*?

Coerced, according to Oxford Languages:

> persuade (an unwilling person) to do something by using force or threats

So uncoerced, the opposite, would seem to be "willing, done entirely of one's own volition".